# Not same environment variables values on ssh

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

I am trying to use remote machine running ubuntu 16.04 using ssh. On this machine I have set `$ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to point to android sdk location. On remote machine if I login locally I am able to see that this variable is correctly set by checking with `echo $ANDROID_HOME`, but the problem is when I am using ssh and `echo $ANDROID_HOME` command it returns empty string. When I tried to see some changes made by me on `$PATH` variables those too are not reflected on ssh. What can be the problem here? I had set these variables in ~/.bashrc file on remote machine, where I appened these lines at the end

`export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/apache-ant-1.10.2/bin:$PATH
export PATH=~/gnuplot-5.2.2:$PATH`

Both of machines are running ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain where you are setting these variables. The problem is caused by the differences between login shells and non-login shells, but we need more details to give a precise answer. See [Sequence of scripts sourced upon login](//askubuntu.com/a/463479)

Comment: @terdon updated.

Comment: Is $ANDROID_HOME exported. Also does the behaviour change, when you use `.profile` to store the variable instead?

Comment: Hang on, are you using Ubuntu on the remote machine?

Comment: @KavehVahedipour If I append those lines in .profile then too I am having same problem.

Comment: So is the variable exported? `export ANDROID_HOME=bla_bla`. Never mind it is.

Comment: what does `PermitUserEnvironment` say in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: @KavehVahedipour What do you mean by that ? It does not contain any line related to above five export commands.

Comment: I wanted to know if `PermitUserEnvironment` is set `true` in  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: @KavehVahedipour When I open that file using ssh there is no line in it containing "PermitUserEnvironment" word.

Comment: Please run `grep PermitUserEnvironment /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: @KavehVahedipour It returns empty.

Comment: Tough one. Do you have a file `.bash_profile` with this content in your ssh directory:
```if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then;
  . ~/.bashrc;
fi```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73444/discussion-between-wss-and-kaveh-vahedipour).